# I cant choose the Saving Options

Tags: rendering, export, image, saving

I started using blender couple of days ago but i think i have come a long way. I finished my first project. I did all the coloring, camera angels etc. When i finished my project i rendered it. But when it comes to saving, saving options not working. I can only save it as a .blender. I cant change it to jpeg or png. When i save it as a .blender and i open it up i cant see the image i rendered. I can only see the tiles like pictures u can see in microsoft excel. When rendering ends i pressed f3 to save it but i can only save it as a .blender and cant change it to any other form. I downloaded the Blender couple of days ago i think its the latest version. How can i solve this issue. TLDR: I cant save the finished project as i wanted to be.

Answer (score 0):

When you save as .blend, you're saving the project, not the rendered image.

When you finish a render an image editor window pops up, showing the rendered image; in this window go to the image menu and choose save as, then you will choose if PNG, jpg, EXR, ...

Shortcut is Alt S.

Comment: The thing is when i choose save as i can only choose the place not the format. So i can only save as .blender. Thats my problem.

Comment: In the 3D window you can save .blend only, in an image editor window you can save images as png, jpg, exr, ....